# Heroku Node.js App Works Locally but not when deployed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, heroku, express

I have a MEAN Stack Heroku app that was running just fine. But then I added a new function:

```
app.get('/userCreated/:id', function(req, res) {

if (req.cookies.userCreated == req.params.id) { 
    res.send(true);
}
else {
    res.send(false);
}

});
```

And now I get a 503 (Service Unavailable) error upon loading the app. Anyone have an idea why this might be?

I'm using Angular and $http.get() to access this Express.js function...

Edit: here is my client side Angular code that is making a call to the server:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
function thisUserCreated(id) {
$http.get('/userCreated/' + id).success(function(data) {
deferred.resolve(data);
// returns boolean indicating whether the current user has the proper cookie
// saying this user created the given group
});
return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: is `bn` accidential or it is part of code

Comment: Woops. Good catch. That's not the issue though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: The `port` you are using for the server, is it free to use on deployment server

Comment: Again, this function was behaving properly on localhost but acts up when deployed to heroku

Comment: @Tushar I believe so. This app was working properly when deployed on Heroku prior to adding this functionality

Comment: @AndrewHansen  are you using correct url while making `$http.get()` call?

Comment: I've updated my question with the client side code that is making the http request. Maybe there's an issue there?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I actually figured it out. Turns out I hadn't listed all my dependencies in my package.json.

Lesson here: when installing node packages always use --save

Or you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in that block of code is inherently broken.

Just check the logs to see what's giving you errors:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the client side code that is making the http request. Maybe there's an issue there?

Comment: If you're getting a 503 on the server, you should really just check the server logs to see why.

Answer (score 1):

Try to recompile (`ng build -prod`) Angular side and deploy it again. Also watch [MEAN Stack Front To Back [Part 10] - App Deployment to Heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBfcbb07Tqk)

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with this problem in many different forms with Node/Heroku exit status 1 and status H10 etc. etc..  I searched and search tried everything from purging the node cache to rolling everything back via git and starting again.  It seemed as though my node_modules kept updating somewhere and I would jump from getting errors to functioning locally to crashing once deployed.  The only thing that finally worked was to "not check in generated directories" in my .gitignore file, which if works for others in this situation seems like a stupid and obvious solution.  The different troubleshooting steps can be found here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys